# Call a method on a class instance (function in class) that calls other functions within that class

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I am working in a Class in Python and it has 3 functions in it. 
Function 1 and Function 2 are acting on their own but function 3 should print what is returned from lets say func_1.
I passed the function names of func_1 into func_3 but I just cant get the right result. When I create an instance of the class named "test", I cant call test.func_3 and I tried everything I know or was able to find on the internet.

Tried to call it without passing func_1 into func_3: 
"NameError: name 'func_1' is not defined"

Passed func_1 into func_3 and called it without argument: 
"TypeError: func_3() missing 1 required positional argument: 'func_1'"

Passed func_1 into func_3 and called it with argument: 
"NameError: name 'func_1' is not defined"

## This is working code (without a class, just some functions:

```
def func_1():
    print("Print func_1 - Print_string")
    return "ReturnFunc1 - Return_string | "

def func_2():
    print("Print func_2 - Print_string")
    return "ReturnFunc2 - Return_string | "

def func_3():
    print("Anything below this line is printed because of calling func_3")
    print("============================================================")
    print("Print func_3 - Print_string")
    print(func_1(), func_2())

func_1()
func_2()
func_3()
```

==================================================================

This is with a class, not working anyhow:

```
class TestingClass():

    def func_1(self):
        print("Print func_1")
        return "ReturnFunc1"

    def func_2(self):
        print("Print func_2")
        return "ReturnFunc2"

    def func_3(self,func_1):
        print("Anything below this line is printed because of calling func_3")
        print("============================================================")
        print("Print func_3")
        print(func_1)

test = TestingClass()
test.func_3(func_1)
```

I would like to achieve the same results as when I code it without Class.

Comment: replace `print(func_1)` by `print(self.func_1())`

Comment: Would he need to call `self.func_1()` if he's passing `test.func_1` ?

Comment: No, but it makes no sense to pass `func_1` as an argument in the first place...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either like this:

```
class TestingClass():

    def func_1(self):
        print("Print func_1")
        return "ReturnFunc1"

    def func_2(self):
        print("Print func_2")
        return "ReturnFunc2"

    def func_3(self,func_1):
        print("Anything below this line is printed because of calling func_3")
        print("============================================================")
        print("Print func_3")
        print(func_1())

test = TestingClass()
test.func_3(test.func_1)
```

Or like this:

```
class TestingClass():

    def func_1(self):
        print("Print func_1")
        return "ReturnFunc1"

    def func_2(self):
        print("Print func_2")
        return "ReturnFunc2"

    def func_3(self):
        print("Anything below this line is printed because of calling func_3")
        print("============================================================")
        print("Print func_3")
        print(self.func_1())

test = TestingClass()
test.func_3()
```

In the first snippet, notice the change from `print(func_1)` to `print(func_1())`. More importantly, also notice the change from `test.func_3(func_1)` to `test.func_3(test.func_1)`.

The second snippet is different in the sense that you are not passing the function to `func_3` anymore, and instead just invoking the class instance's `func_1` method directly.

Comment: you should only show the second one, why would be the interest of passing as an argument a method of the very same class?

Comment: Because the OP said he "would like to achieve the same results as when [he] code[s] it without Class". I totally agree with you though, the first option shows a lack of understanding of classes - however, there is no way of knowing what the OP actually intends on doing with these functions. Perhaps he/she really does not a function that takes a function as parameter? With the second approach `func_3` would only be able to operate on one member function.

Comment: I really don't think OP will need to pass a funciton as an argument. more probably, he does not fully understand how classes and methods should be used, and that's why I think the first option is confusing and won't help him to understand how things work...

Comment: @user10987432 Thank you very much for your time and effort. It fixed my problem and helps me understand the concept of functions within classes.

Comment: @olinox14 Thank you for your comments, they are valuable for me.

Answer (score 0):

Playing around with your case, you can use global if you want to call `func_1()` outside the class and treat it as normal function instead of method.

```
class TestingClass():

    global func_1

    def func_1():
        print("Print func_1")
        return "ReturnFunc1"

    def func_2(self):
        print("Print func_2")
        return "ReturnFunc2"

    def func_3(self, func_1):
        print("Anything below this line is printed because of calling func_3")
        print("============================================================")
        print("Print func_3")
        print(func_1)


test = TestingClass()
test.func_3(func_1())
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, solution and comment Jourmaico, the solution above from "user10987432" is what i wanted to achieve.